# Rails console sql query only returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rails-console

I am issuing an SQL statement in console:

```
> sql = "SELECT flavour from Libation where id=8675309"
> result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
=> true
```

Am using the oracle enhanced adapter, and wonder why I only get true. I was expecting something like "mango". I have tried many things and no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `select_all` instead of `execute`?

Comment: @Nishu - reply with an answer and I will pick you. I feel silly now that I did not think of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `select_all` instead of `execute` to fetch results.